# Find cells in Excel-Table which contain parameter x but don't contain parameter y

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have an Excel Table looking something like this:

| column 1 | column 2 |
| --- | --- |
| D4:some stuff... D5: some stuff |  |
| D4:some stuff.... |  |
| D4: some stuff... D5:some stuff |  |

The tags D4 and D5 are usually pairs and occur in the same cell, but sometimes there is only the tag D4 in a cell without a D5. Is it possible to filter the cells with a D4 tag but without a D5 Tag?

Answer (score 0):

If you have the newest version of Excel you can try:

```
=FILTER(range, ((ISNUMBER(SEARCH("D4", range)))*
(NOT(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("D5", range))))))
```

For example:
[image]

If you don't have the newest version, you can use a similar strategy with an extra step. First use something like

```
=IF(AND(
ISNUMBER(SEARCH("D4", A1)), NOT(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("D5", range)))), 
1,0)
```

then drag down to every cell in your range, highlight both the original data and new column, go Data->Filter, and select only 1's.